# DELETING NULL ERROR MSG APPEARING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, dml

I am trying to delete away all the rows with NULL. I tried using the code:

```
DELETE FROM [FILENAME] WHERE [MONTH] = 'NULL'
```

But the error msg appears as:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I'm guessing i have to convert something but got no clue. Any help will be great. thanks

Comment: Use `IS` not `=` when looking for nullity: `... where [month] IS NULL`

Comment: `'NULL'` is a string constant (which by definition isn't null). `NULL` is the actual keyword to check for null values

Answer (score 2):

The error is because (NULL) is not a value and not a string value to put it between two single quotation marks('').
NULLs have special ways and special functions to deal with it, so you can use this code to delete away all the rows with NULL

```
DELETE FROM [FILENAME] WHERE [MONTH] IS NULL
```